# How to close activity with old preferences data?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I am developing an android app with preferences. I have 2 activities: MainActivity and PrefActivity. At MainActivity I am show textview with value from preferences. At PrefActivity I change this value from ListPreference.
When i press back button in the PrefActivity, it is refer me to the MainActivity with text of new value from preferences. But if i press back button once more, then it refer me to the old MainActivity with text of old value from preference. How I can escape from the old MainActivity?
Code of retrieve value from preferences:

```
sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String sharedpreferences = sp.getString("sharedpreference", "");
TextView tv_info = findviewbyid(R.id.tvinfo);
tv_info.settext(sharedpreferences);
```

Comment: Please paste the code

Comment: @vaibhavkumar code of what?

Comment: you need to update the mainactivity after visiting the pref activity correct ??

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan yes

Comment: can you please share the code to set the data from the shared preference and set it to textview in main activity ?

Comment: MainActivity and PrefActivity classes code. Because i am think that you overide the onBackPressed method in PrefActivity and calling MainActivity from there.

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan added

Comment: you will be adding them in the oncreate ??

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan yea

Comment: Just add the same in the onresume overide method.

Comment: do you got it fixed @ОлегМедведев

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan no ,v

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123352/discussion-between-ragu-swaminathan-and--).

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan  I need to close old mainactivity while i loading new MainActivity. Otherwords, i want to exit the app when i press back button on the new MainActivity. Old MainActivity = MainActivity with old data

Comment: Kindly check this flow --> MainActivity [display data from SP] --> PrefActivity [change the SP values] --> clicking back in prefactivity ---> show the mainActivity with updated SP values. is this correct ?

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan, yes, it is correct. But flow, that i have:  MainActivity [display data from SP] --> PrefActivity [change the SP values] --> clicking back in prefactivity ---> show the mainActivity with updated SP values -> **clicking back in MainActivity -> show the MainActivity with old data**

Comment: what about the flow you have ?? is it same or different. ?

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan, Flow I Need: MainActivity [display data from SP] --> PrefActivity [change the SP values] --> clicking back in prefactivity ---> show the mainActivity with updated SP values -> **clicking back in mainactivity -> close the app (exit mainactivity)**

Comment: can you please share your preference activity and snippets in mainactivity to open preference activity.

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan  do you need java code of  my preferences activity?

Comment: yes for both the activities

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan can i share code with you in the chat?

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan look to the chat please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly check the below logic and implement.

**Your MainActivity**

```
if (id == R.id.action_settings) { 
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PrefActivity.class); 
intent.putExtra("fwflag","from_menu_item"); 
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Remove your implementation of setting data from the shared preference from oncreate method, and paste it to the onResume method:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String sharedpreferences = sp.getString("sharedpreference", "");
TextView tv_info = findviewbyid(R.id.tvinfo);
tv_info.settext(sharedpreferences);
}
```

**Then in your PrefActivity**

update the below code - remove onbackpressed() and put finish().

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
@Override 
public void onClick(View v) { 
finish(); 
}
```

**Under PrefFragment**

remove the below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(PrefActivity.this, MainActivity.class); 
startActivity(intent);
```

and just put

```
finish();
```

and now try.

Let me know for queries.

Comment: Ok. I can now exit the app for single back button click! But, when I change preference, textview is not apply new value. Only when I close the app and open it again, it show me new value. What I need to do to show text normally?

Comment: I have already tried to check logs, and it shows me that onResume method is working. Strangely(

Comment: check whether the value of shared preference received inside the onresume by printing that value.

Comment: i print the value of shared preference in the logs. It is matches the new value. But problem is not solved....

Comment: i print the value of shared preference in the logs. It is matches the new value. But problem is not solved....

Comment: can you try declaring the textview globally and check

Comment: no, i have done other sample, with showing text in the toolbar, and there is the same problem( I have declared toolbar globally in the java file. Any guesses?

Comment: can you share the logic you implemented in the main activity code

Comment: do you need the code of how i implement toolbar and how i set text of toolbar?

Comment: do you need the code of how i implement toolbar and how i set text of toolbar?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123495/discussion-between-ragu-swaminathan-and--).

Comment: thank you. Everything is working fine. Please approve my edit for your answer)